# How to navigate particular search page in App store?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, app-store, uidocumentinteraction

In my app i am opening documents via UIDocumentInteractionController. if no apps is installed in device we want to navigate to app store.In that place i want to navigate to document viewer related apps page.

if anyone can suggest me.

Answer (score 0):

You can open the App Store to an app page by getting the app page url. On iOS, you can go to the app page, click share and copy the url.

Then, you can open it like this (Swift) :

```
let theURL = NSURL(urlWithString: "app url here")
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(theURL)
```

If that answers your question.

Comment: i want to navigate to the search page not an app page

Comment: I'm not sure you can, but you could try looking up the App Store's URL scheme to see if it is possible. I've never seen an iOS app do it though.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is use iTunes search query and it will navigate to a an 'app like' visual:

```
http://itunes.com/Dropbox
```

Where 'DropBox' is your search term. This is what it looks like on device :

[image: pic1]

Or you can do it to a specific category:

```
http://itunes.apple.com/genre/mobile-software-applications/id6002?mt=8
```